# Set new dataframe labels

Tags: rename

I have been importing data from excel as an DataFrame but receive extremely long labels for each series. I want to exchange all labels for shorter ones. As I understand it if I use the rename function I need to write the full old label names which is problematic as it is so long. Is there any way to do this easier. Perhaps using index[:1] as reference for the old labeel or any other way?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using Python in Spyder 4.0